# Why doesn't Vim recognize HTML inside PHP?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-php

The HTML that's being returned by this PHP function doesn't have any syntax highlighting.

If I delete the `'` on line 13 the HTML highlighting works (but the PHP function breaks), with it the HTML highlighting does not work.

How do I get the HTML to have its proper syntax highlighting inside of this function?

[image: html loses syntax highlighting inside php return function]

Do I want to be doing [something like this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file)?  I'm having a hard time figuring out what to make of that and how I would adapt it for my situation, let alone whether or not that's the right approach.

It would be great if Vim could automatically recognize HTML inside a PHP file without having to type any hard-to-remember commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`:help ft-php-syntax`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#ft%2dphp%2dsyntax):

```
There are the following options for the php syntax highlighting.

[..]

Enable HTML syntax highlighting inside strings:

  let php_htmlInStrings = 1
```

You can add that your vimrc.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  I didn't even know there was an option of "ft-php-" for the syntax help.  Adding that `let php_...` to .vimrc did the trick!