# .php file makes html text same color as html attributes - how to fix?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-php

The text inside of `<p>` tags is the same color as the html attributes, so it's hard to distinguish between them.

[image]

The html inside this .php file is colored (line one of this image) almost identically to the html inside an .html file (second line of this image), except for this subtle yet major difference.  The words "This is also red" should be black instead.

How do I customize/override the color that one of these (either the p text or the attributes) is displayed in in php files?  Or how can I make it automatically match the colors exactly how they are in an html file?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Carpetsmoker, that's exactly my problem.  How to make "This is also red" black instead?

Comment: Maybe this post can help you : http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/why-doesnt-vim-recognize-html-inside-php?rq=1

Comment: That was my previous question, this one is a continuation of that ;^)

Comment: This is probably because by default the content of strings is shown in red. So "standard text" even though it's part of your HTML is going to be shown in the default string color. i.e. if you were to write another string without HTML, it would most certainly be red, right?